# Spotfire - Limit data using expression based upon marking in related graph

Tags: spotfire

I'm stuck on Spotfire visualizations, hoping you guys can help.

My data contains individuals and how much they've borrowed on a loan, along with other attributes.   The data is laid down daily.

Example:

**Date**    | **Individual** | **Borrowed Amount** | **Loan Amount**

03/01/2018 | Tony  | $1.1MM | $1.3MM

03/01/2018 | Tina  | $505k  | $1.8MM

03/02/2018 | Tony  | $1.0MM | $1.3MM

03/02/2018  | Tina | $495k  | $1.8MM

I've created a table where only the most recent day shows (which is working fine).  What I now want to do is create a related visualization that shows a line graph of an individuals historical borrowing **based on the line/individual selected in the table**.

I think I need to use the 'limit data using expression' functionality on the line graph under the 'Data' tab, but what is the syntax for a marked value?  Or am I thinking about it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

while it's possible to use a data-limiting expression on your line chart, you'll be much better off (and so will your users!) if you use the [Marking](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.9.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-A7EA416F-DDB8-4755-BC4B-14850FF41A9D.html) feature. the quickest way to configure this is to right click your table visualization and choose **Create details visualization » Line chart**.

this will limit the line chart based on the data selected in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I want to limit the line chart based on the individual selected, but then I don't want to limit the line chart based on the date.  A row in the table will show Tony's borrowings for March 1st.  I want to click on that line in the table, then the line graph shows Tony's borrowings but for all previous dates.  is this possible?

Comment: it is possible, but you'll need a separate table with all the names (or IDs), then create a table relation (Edit...Data Table Properties...Relations) in order to do this